# Difference between perl commands '=>' and '='

Tags: perl, mason

What is the difference between the following perl/mason commands.

$test = $test1;
$test => $test1;

specifically how does the instantiation work here?

Comment: Was this question about about the normal initialization using `=` and then inside the `<%args>` using `=>` ?

Answer (score 9):

[Mason](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Mason) is a Perl framework for those who don't know...

The `=` is a Perl assignment operator. The `=>` is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the `,` operator. It's used mainly for hashes to help associate the key to the value. The following three are equivelent:

```
my %hash = ("red", "apple", "yellow", "lemon", "green", "lime");

my %hash = (red => "apple", yellow => "lemon", green => "lime");

my %hash = ("red", apple => "yellow", lemon => "green", "lime");
```

- The first looks like it could be just a list. I'd have to pay close attention to see it's `%hash` and not `@hash`. Plus, if I had 100 key value pairs and not just 3 of them, you could start losing track which are  the keys and which are the values.
- The second makes it very clear that `red` is the key to the value `apple`, and that `yellow` is the key to `lemon`, etc. Note too that I no longer need quotes around my keys as long as my keys follow Perl variable name conventions (although they can contain one or two dashes in front).
- The third is there just to mess with your mind. And to show you that `=>` is *merely* syntactic sugar and doesn't necessarily link what comes before with what comes after it. To Perl, it's just a list separator. Your brain is the one that forms the association.

You see `=>` used in function called like this:

```
my_function(
   -bar   => $bar_value,
   -fubar => $fu_value,
   -futz  => $futz_value,
);
```

This is a function called `myFunction` that takes a keyed set of values as a parameter. I could have done this too:

```
my_function("-bar", "$bar_value", "-fubar", $fu_value, "-futz", "$futz_value");
```

However, this function does something like this:

```
sub my_function {
   my %params = @_;
```

so, it's using a hash for it's parameters and not merely a list. Functions tend to use hashes when the order of the parameters may get confusing because it's so long, or many parameters the function uses are optional. Imagine a function that may require a user ID and password, but not necessarily require one.

You can use the `=>` in any situation rather than a comma. For example, the latest style in Perl is not to use parentheses for function arguments:

```
chomp $foo;
```

is cleaner than:

```
chomp( $foo );
```

But, this sometimes harder to read when your function has multiple parameters:

```
join ", ", @foo;
```

I'll sometimes use the `=>` to replace the command in these situations:

```
join ", " => @foo;
```

Now, I can see that ", " and `@foo` are both parameters to the `join` function. Be careful, or it'll bite you:

```
my @array = ( join ", " => @foo, @bar);
```

is the same as:

```
my @array = ( join ", ", @foo, @bar );
```

or

```
my @array = ( join (", ", @foo, @bar ) );
```

and not:

```
my @array = ( join (", ", @foo) , @bar);
```

Just because I used `=>` only between `", "` and `@foo` doesn't mean that `@bar` isn't part of the parameters!

Comment: You implied but didn't state explicitly that the `=>` sugar also includes auto-quoting the left operand.

Comment: I did state that in my second bullet point: _Note too that I no longer need quotes around my keys as long as my keys follow Perl variable name conventions (although they can contain one or two dashes in front)._ However, after playing around, I realize a double dashes don't work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Perl or Mason? I don't know Mason, so I'll answer about Perl.

«`=`» is the assignment operator.

```
$test = 'test';  # $test now contains the 4-char string "test".
```

«`=>`» is a fancy version of «`,`» that auto-quotes its left-hand side. The following are all equivalent:

```
print "a", "b";
print "a" => "b";
print a => "b";    # Auto-quoting in effect
```

Neither has anything to do with instantiation, although Perl will automatically instantiate a package variable when it's used. This is generally a bad idea, and is disabled by `use strict;`. (Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!)

Operators are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is a great answer about the Perl assignment operator `=` and the syntactic sugar for the `,` operator. But if you are using HTML::Mason, the `=>` operator can also have an additional meaning.

A Mason component can take a variety of arguments, from either an external source (an HTTP request) or an internal one (one component calling another), and declaring the names and the datatypes of the arguments is done via the `<%args>` block:

```
<%args>
  $width
  $admin => 0  # A default value
  @items => ( 1, 2, 'something else' )
  %pairs => ( key1 => 1, key2 => 'value' )
</%args>
```

here the `=>` operator is used to specify a default value. And a component can call another component using for example the ampersand tag, without specifying any argument:

```
<& menu &>
```

or specifying some arguments using the `=>` operator:

```
<& menu, width => 640, admin => 1 &>
```

you can have a look at the Components chapter of the [Mason Book](http://www.masonbook.com/book/chapter-2.mhtml).

In Mason2 (simply called Mason) the `<%args>` block is gone, you can still call components using the `<& &>` tag but to declare attributes you have to use Moose 'has' syntax within a `<%class>` section:

```
<%class>
  has 'foo';
  has 'bar' => (required => 1);
  has 'baz' => (isa => 'Int', default => 17);
</%class>
```

some reference here: [Mason::Manual::Components](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.20/lib/Mason/Manual/Components.pod).